# How to use structs from a dll in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, struct

I have a third party dll with no lib or header file to use in my c++ app. That's why I use LoadLibrary(_T("xxx.dll")) to load it. And I can reach its functions with GetProcAddress() function.

There is a struct in this dll and I have to reach it too. What should I do to reach and use it? I have looked over the site but found just examples with c# not c++. What is the way of doing this in c++?

Thanks...

Comment: By struct, do you mean the definition or an instantiated one? In any case, you can't access the data layout of the struct from the DLL, you need the original definition.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a "struct in this dll". DLLs don't contain structs, they contain functions and data, not types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the syntax of the struct, for example from a C# definition then you can simply add its definition to a .h file, include it in your C++ source file and use it. that's all.
but if your struct is some kind of class and has member methods then you should know the decorated name of member methods, load them from .dll dynamically and call them as C functions.

Comment: Take care of memory alignment if this DLL is compiled with different memory alignment you may do use #pragma push and #pragma pop to override the new struct you are going to define to force it to use the same memory alignment too. Good luck

Comment: I know the syntax of the struct and it has no member methods. So can I just write a struct with the same syntax and use it?

Comment: so let's say that the struct in dll is like this:
    `typedef struct
        {
                int x;
                int array[100];
        } Foo;`

Will I define the same in the c++ side and use it as it is?

Comment: @rendar: If you need a structure like that in your code, then you should define one. If not, don't. It's very hard to understand your question because you haven't really explained it clearly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: What I try to do is this. There is a function in the dll which takes a parameter in the type of a struct defined also in the dll. I have to call the function but I don't know how to pass a parameter in that struct type. Because I don't know how to get that type. I was asking if it is it ok that I define the same struct in my app and pass a parameter to the function from that struct type?

Comment: @rendar: You'll have to try it. It may or may not work. If you get the memory representation precisely the same, it should work so long as no memory is allocated on one side of the DLL boundary and freed on the other side.

Comment: Struct is just a an assumption of the memory. for example in you Foo struct you say we have `sizeof(int) * 101` bytes of memory( forget about memory packing for now! ) and I want to use its first `sizeof(int)` as an int and the rest as an array of ints. so there is nothing that need to implemented in the DLL, it is only logical and no physical code is required to use that struct in you C++ code. just declare it and use it in your code. since you say that it is used in C# I don't think that memory packing generate a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer:
You can use GetProcAddress to retrieve the address of a variable declared as a struct. From [the GetProcAddress man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx):

Retrieves the address of an exported function or **variable** from the specified dynamic-link library (DLL).

The name of that function should be GetSymAddress rather than GetProcAddress, but I digress.

Long Answer:

Provided that the DLL contains a symbol **instance** of type struct Foo:

```
typedef struct { int x; int array[100]; } Foo;
__declspec( dllexport )  struct Foo Bar = 
{
0xdeadbeef,{0}
};
```

You **can** retrieve the address of the variable **Bar** provided you have already loaded the dll and have its hModule handle somewhere with:

```
struct Foo* Bar = GetProcAddress(hModule,"Bar");
```

You **cannot** retrieve the definition of the structure itself, but I do not think that's what you meant anyhow.

Note: I have overlooked name mangling, extern "C" declarations and maybe some other things you need to keep into consideration to make the point clear, I assume the reader already has a basic grasp of the topics at hand.